# stripe-signature validation error in Azure Python serverless function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, stripe-payments, httprequest

I'm setting up a webhook in Azure serverless functions using Python to capture details when a Stripe payment is completed.  As part of this it is reccomended practice to validate that the API call has originated from Stripe.  Stripe passes a stripe-signature as part of the request header, but I am getting an error message from validation that the signatures don't match.
I'm pretty sure it is because I am using req.get_json() to parse the request body and this changes the original payload so when you pass it back to Stripe, the checksum doesn't work.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import json

import stripe

endpoint_secret = 'whsec_..........'

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    event = None
    req_body = req.get_json()
    payload = req_body.get('data')
    logging.warning('Stripe Webhook initiated')
    logging.warning(req.headers.get('stripe-signature'))
    logging.warning(payload)
    try:
        event = payload
    except:
        logging.warning('Webhook error while parsing basic request.')
        return json.dumps({"success":"False"})
    if endpoint_secret:
        # Only verify the event if there is an endpoint secret defined
        # Otherwise use the basic event deserialized with json
        sig_header = req.headers.get('stripe-signature')
        try:
            event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
                payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
            )
        except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
            logging.warning('Webhook signature verification failed.' + str(e))
            return json.dumps({"success":"False"})
```

If I use req_body = req.get_body() how do I then get the 'data' object out of the byte string so that it truely represents EXACTLY what Stripe sent in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

As usual,  posting the question on SO leads me in a new direction for googling the answer..
instead of

```
    req_body = req.get_json()
    payload = req_body.get('data')
```

I used

```
    req_body = req.get_body()
    payload = req_body.decode('UTF-8')
```

and this seems to have done the trick. I've spent 3 hours on this so I hope the post helps someone else.

Comment: i feel your pain my friend - going through the exact same thing myself right now!